# Cubic Residues mod p

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Suppose that $p > 3$ is prime, and suppose that $r$ is a primitive root mod $p$. Prove that if $p ≡ 1$ mod $3$ then $r$ is a cubic non-residue mod $p$.

---

I have tried to manipulate the Euler Criterion and Legendre symbols, but I cannot get to a point where I can introduce the primitive root $r$.

Comment: the product of two cubic residues is another cubic residue. How many of these are there?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** If $p\equiv1\pmod{3}$ then $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, which is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

On a finite abelian group of order $n$, the map $x \mapsto x^3$ is a homomorphism; it is a bijection iff $\gcd(3,n)=1$.
This is proved easily by considering the kernel.
Since $3$ is prime, $\gcd(3,n)=1$ iff $n \not \equiv 0 \bmod 3$.

In our case, $n=p-1$. If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, then $\gcd(3,n)=3 > 1$ and the map $x \mapsto x^3$ is not surjective. Therefore, $r$ is not in the image.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225412/show-x-mod-p-is-a-cubic-residue-iff-xp-1-3-equiv-1-mod-p.