# When is $2023$ a cubic residue residue mod $p$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cubic-reciprocity

When is $2023$ a cubic residue residue mod $p$ that is $1\pmod{3}$?

I do know about quadratic reciprocity, since $x^{2}\equiv2023\pmod{p}$ is only solvable if $p\equiv\pm1\pm3\pm9\pmod{28}$, but I don’t know when $x^{3}\equiv2023\pmod{p}$ is solvable.

I know about cubic reciprocity, but I don’t know if it will work in the similar way as Legendre symbol.

For instance, there is 14 prime number years in this century, but $2089$ is the only prime number year in this century, where $x^{3}\equiv2023\pmod{2089}$ is solvable. $2089$ is a prime that is $1\pmod{3}$.

Hint: $p$ must be $1\pmod{3}$, and $2023=17^{2}\cdot7.$

Comment: I have almost no clue about cubic reciprocity , but my guess is that this classification is  much harder than for the square-residues.

Comment: I think this post would be some hint for you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225412/show-x-mod-p-is-a-cubic-residue-iff-xp-1-3-equiv-1-mod-p?rq=1).